# Counting the number of times a word appears for a value in a row

Tags: excel

I am looking to work out how many times a word appears for a given name. For example I have students and their grades listed in one sheet as:

```
Dave Merit
Dave Distinction
Simon Merit
Tammy Pass
Dave Pass
Dave Merit
Simon Pass
```

In the next sheet I want to have a count. So for `Dave` - how many a) "Distinction"s he has, b) how many "merit"s he has, then the same for `Simon` and `Tammy`.

I start looking at VLOOKUP but it drives me bonkers.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [COUNTIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIFS-function-53C4DC8E-0E5B-4E32-93DF-9CA5E7DA89ED).

For Dave's merits,

```
=countifs(A:A, "Dave", B:B, "merit")
'or with Dave in D1 and merit in D2 as,
=countifs(A:A, D1, B:B, D2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Pivot Table.
Add a header row to the columns:  e.g. `Name` and `Grade`.
Drag Name to the rows; Grade to the columns; Grade to the Values.
Format to taste:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should use the countif function.

=countif(A:A, B1)
with A:A the column where to look and B1 the field you are looking for.

If you want to match substrings you have to split the field. 
An easy way to do that is to use "text to columns" function in excel.And split based on the "space" character.
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Split-text-into-different-cells-30b14928-5550-41f5-97ca-7a3e9c363ed7